# Multi-IP address zimbra server DNS PTR records and spam

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, spam, zimbra

We have a mail server running Zimbra (ZCS 6.0.8). The server has 5 active public IP addresses in the same subnet. (`.226`-`.230`). I currently have `A` records for each of these (`host0.domain.com`..`host4.domain.com`), with the main `host.domain.com` of the machine pointing to `.226`.

Our host has ended up being listed on the [SORBS DUHL list](http://www.sorbs.net/overview.shtml) (even though it's in a server farm). According to them you can get [removed quickly](http://www.sorbs.net/faq/dul.shtml) by checking that your host has an `MX` record, an `A` record, and a `PTR` record that points back to the hostname given in the `MX` record.

I tried setting the `PTR` records so that each of these addresses resolved back to their `A` record (i.e. `.228` had a `PTR` to `host2.domain.com`). However, I then got mail being rejected from other servers because when Postfix (under Zimbra control) sends out mail, it uses the main hostname for the `HELO` - there doesn't seem to be any way to override it. So the `PTR` records currently say `host.domain.com` for all 5 IP addresses.

What's the correct way to handle this? Should I have an `A` record for the domain that points to all the IP addresses (for round-robin handling)? I'm nervous of changes that could cause problems, so I'm wondering what the standard way to handle a multiple-IP-address mail server is.

Comment: It seems that the multiple-address thing is not an issue with SORBS; they've blocked the whole range and so should unblock it if demonstrated that one IP address is a valid mail server (unfortunately they've cached my old DNS and so their automatic exclusion tool is failing)

Comment: It also seems that HELO can now be configured: http://www.kutukupret.com/2010/01/02/postfix-bind-sender-domain-to-dedicated-outgoing-ip-address/

Comment: That `HELO` setup requires `postfix-2.7-20091209`; ZCS is on `postfix-2.6.7.2z`

Comment: Ah, Zimbra 7.0b3 now contains `postfix-2.7.1.2z` - hopefully when the final 7.0 is released it will then support the `HELO` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no specific reason you want/need a service to listen to multiple addresses, it always makes troubleshooting a lot less complicated if you can decide on **one** address to bind to. This is a generally good practice, and especially true for protocols such as SMTP which may attempt to match reverse DNS lookups with source addresses at [level 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7:_Application_Layer).

Some suggestions:

- Make the Postfix SMTP client part of Zimbra bind only to your "main" IP. Either you must edit [`/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/master.cf.in`](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) adding an address to the `smtp` line [like this](http://new.spheron1.co.uk/2009/10/19/binding-zimbra-to-an-ip/) - see below. (Or to set [`inet_interfaces`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces) using [zmlocalconfig](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Tuning_Postfix_Queue_Settings), but this doesn't work)
- Verify that you have a corresponding A and PTR (no round-robin records or anything).
- Verify that you have servername/hostname & mail domain name setup correctly in Zimbra. Best verified by sending a test email somewhere and then inspecting the mail headers.
- Make sure you have restart the corresponding daemons when necessary.

Here's the syntax for adjusting the `smtp` line:

> `smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp`
>   `-o smtp_bind_address=n.n.n.n`

Comment: Thanks; the SMTP client part could help us here. (All the A and PTR records are correct; there are no round-robin records). Listening on multiple addresses is not so much the problem as sending from multiple... the "smtp" line in master.cf.in specifies a listening service and so does `inet_interfaces`, but `smtp_bind_address` seems to be the right one to just adjusting client connections

Comment: Unfortunately setting `smtp_bind_address` seemed to prevent our server from delivering any mail at all; will need to investigate/try other options

Comment: Keep in mind that it's likely you still need to explicitly listen on `127.0.0.1` in addition to the one you intend binding on. Failing that will quite likely stop delivery (as well as look-prevention) from working.

Comment: ..."loop-prevention" of course ;)

Comment: conny - thanks that's interesting; however I still had `inet_interfaces` set to all; would adjusting `smtp_bind_address` cause a problem without explicitly setting `inet_addresses` to list the IP addresses?

Comment: I've now tested adjusting the smtp 465 and submission lines in master.cf.in; they result in the server listening on only one address, but the client still sends out from multiple addresses

Comment: Trying to set smtp_bind_address as an option on the outgoing smtp in master.cf.in worked! (It required restarting the whole of Zimbra, not just the mta)